# Why are comment upvotes prevented after being undone?

Tags: support, comments

Why can we not upvote a comment a second time? We upvote comment once, then we undo it and then again if we try to upvote, it says 
**You've already undone your vote on this comment; you cannot upvote it again**. Of course we get an alert before we undo, saying that we cannot upvote again, fair enough, but my question is, why do we have such a restriction?

Comment: Well, just to add to the answer below, think of it as an answer. Just like votes on answers lock after 5 minutes, it's about the same for comments. Yeah, you can reset an answer vote, but the answer *has to be edited*. *Comments can't be edited* after 5 minutes in which they are posted.

Comment: But you can star something after you've already starred it. So you're essentially proving my point. @pnuts

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's so you don't keep wasting your time on a comment. Upvote or not, make up your mind right there and then. And then move on. There are bigger fish to fry.

The undo feature is largely intended for undoing misclicks.

Comment: Damn.. Pretty neat answer.. _There are bigger fish to fry_ made me smile after I read it, but yea it justifies.. Thank you.. :)

Comment: I've wondered this before, and this question makes a lot of sense. Might be useful to add that to the popup.

Comment: Doesn't this feel like nannying to anyone else? Adding a restriction to a piece of software as some kind of emotional therapy seems a step too far to me. If I've upvoted a comment by mistake, found an error in it, pointed it out, then someone edits the comment to correct it, I want to be able to re-upvote it, and I see no actual reason to be prevented from doing so other than a sort of condescending "stop wasting your time" social engineering measure. I don't buy the "there are bigger fish to fry" concept at all - it's _my_ choice what I spend my time on, not yours!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: so you assume you read a comment, upvote it, undo the upvote, add another comment and the other user fixes the error in his comment, all within the first five minutes of the existence of the comment? That sounds like a rare case to me…

Comment: @Holger: Yes, it's a rare case. But you add a Ux restriction when you _need_ to, not because you want to socially engineer people and there are only rare cases in which you'd need _not_ to. That's fundamental. I can't claim that this hits me often in practice, but there's also a principle. And, more than much else, I guess I'm saying that I don't buy this particular justification for the restriction. I'm not necessarily saying it must be lifted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yea.. Your point seems valid.. Never thought in that perspective.. but yea it stands valid...

Comment: @pnuts: If anything it seems to me that this restriction adds operational complexity rather than removing it.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Haven't you heard? Stack Exchange is *all* about nannying and handholding.

Comment: But in all seriousness, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032 where others have expressed similar sentiments re: nannying. I'm just telling it like it is.

Comment: @BoltClock: There was a rumour :P So _"we do not want flip flopping"_ is the official rationale? I see.

Comment: I always assumed that there was some convoluted way that comment upvote + undo + upvote could be abused. Learning that some coder just decided that people shouldn't be doing that and then actually implemented a restriction (that even has everyone click through a warning message on undo) blows my mind.

Comment: And I witness one more instance where comments get more upvotes than question and answer.. @LightnessRacesinOrbit :D

Comment: This is a garbage feature that needs to be removed. I read a comment and upvote it, but undo because I just need to quickly check if it really works. A minute later I came back to confirm and upvote it for real and now it's locked forever.

Comment: But I misclicked the "undo upvote"... This doesn't make any sense to me, why would they care how much time someone spends on a comment?

Answer (score -3):

While I don't know why such a policy exists at Stack Overflow in particular, I would suggest that imposing such a limitation simplifies the database design and makes it easier to maintain consistency.

It's often useful to allow a database system to use two or more databases,
with some users connected to one, some connected to another, and with the
two databases synchronizing/reconciling their contents on an as-convenient
basis.  If the state of each comment's votes were kept as a list of people
who had up-voted it, but withdrawal of votes was permitted, there would be
no way to distinguish the scenario where someone was added to one database
and had not yet added to the other, from the scenario where someone had
been added to both databases and subsequently removed from one.

The simplest way to allow up-votes to be withdrawn is to keep a list of
people who had up-voted a comment, and a list of people who had cancelled
an up-vote.  Under that design, the add-and-cancel scenario can be easily
distinguished from the new-addition scenario, since in either case two
databases can be reconciled by adding to either list in either database
any user that is present in the corresponding list in the other database.

To allow votes to be cast and cancelled in arbitrary fashion, it would
become necessary to determine whether an addition or cancellation happened
last.  While there are certainly ways of accomplishing that (e.g. via
timestamps) and while Stack Overflow in fact takes care of that with
votes on questions and answers, comments greatly outnumber questions and
answers, and it's thus desirable that their implementation be cheaper.

Comment: I'm sure that such a feature (allowing re-upvoting of comments) would be an easy task to create in comparison to some of the other stuff (*surely the table field in the database for it would be a `true` or `false`, not dissimilar to how post votes work)*).

Comment: @cybermonkey: If one merely keeps track of "true" or "false", one still ends up in trouble if one database says a person's last action on a comment was an up-vote and the other says the last action was the cancellation of an up-vote.  There are remedies, such as using date-stamps or counters (e.g. if one database says the last action was the 59th casting of an up-vote while the other says its last action was the 58th cancellation of an up-vote, the 59th casting should win) but again, I don't think the System wanted to keep that much state.